# Fourier Transform of Exponential Integral combination $e^{-x}\operatorname{Ei}(x)-e^{x}\operatorname{Ei}(-x)$

Tags: integration, special-functions, fourier-transform

When trying to solve an ODE using Fourier methods, I met the following solution:

$$\omega \left(e^{-\omega}\operatorname{Ei}(\omega) - e^{ax}\operatorname{Ei}(-\omega)\right)$$

Which I have to Fourier transform back. I attempted using my '**dirty physics**' approach:

1. Use the definition of the Exponential Integral to write,
   $$ \operatorname{Ei}(\omega) = -\int_{-\omega}^\infty \text{d}t~ t^{-1} e^{-t} = e^\omega \int_0^\infty \, \text{d}u\frac{e^{-u}}{\omega-u}$$
   And thus we can write the combination in the brackets as
   $$e^{-\omega}\operatorname{Ei}(\omega)-e^{\omega}\operatorname{Ei}(-\omega) = 2\omega\int_0^\infty \text{d}u \, \frac{e^{-u}}{\omega^2-u^2} $$
2. Do the Fourier transform for the above by changing the order of integration,
   \begin{align}
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\text{d}\omega}{2\pi} ~e^{i\omega x}\left[ e^{-\omega} \operatorname{Ei}(\omega)-e^\omega \operatorname{Ei}(-\omega)\right] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\text{d}\omega}{2\pi}~e^{i\omega x} 2\omega\int_0^\infty \text{d}u \, \frac{e^{-u}}{\omega^2-u^2}\\
   &= \int_0^\infty \text{d}u~ e^{-u} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\text{d}\omega}{2\pi}~\frac{2\omega}{\omega^2-u^2}e^{i\omega x}\\
   &=i\operatorname{sgn}(x)\int_{0}^{\infty} \text{d}u~ e^{-u} \cos(xu)\\
   &=i~\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}{1+x^2}
   \end{align}
3. Use the usual property of the Fourier Transform that $\mathcal{F}[i\omega f(\omega)] = \partial_x f(x)$,
   \begin{align}
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\text{d}\omega}{2\pi} ~e^{i\omega x} \omega\left[ e^{-\omega}\operatorname{Ei}(\omega)-e^\omega \operatorname{Ei}(-\omega)\right] = \partial_x \left(\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x)}{1+x^2}\right) = \frac{2\delta(x)}{1+x^2}-\frac{2|x|}{(1+x^2)^2}
   \end{align}

However if you evaluate the above in Mathematica, I get simply $2\delta(x)$ as the result, which is the first piece of the above.

**Does anyone know where I am messing it up and would be able to help with a rigorous treatment?**

Comment: The solution cannot be simply $2\delta(x)$ because its Fourier transform is constant, which $w (e^{-w}\text{Ei}(w) - e^w \text{Ei}(-w)$ isn't. Did you double check the Mathematica input? Anyway I went over the solution and it looks good to me. When in doubt you can of course simply verify your result with the original ODE.

Comment: @Hyperplane, thank you for pointing out. It is true that it cannot be simply $2\delta(x)$. I more or less have pinned down the problem with Mathematica. First I noticed that asking for the FT of $\omega(\dots+\dots)$ returns the $2\delta(x)$ while asking for $(\omega\times\dots+\omega\times\dots)$ returns the result I quote above. Further, I noticed that doing this only happens in my lab machine, and not on my personal laptop. So they must have corrected some mistake in the FT function.

Comment: Btw I am happy to give the bounty for someone that can justify rigorously this result above - the existence of the first FT, why Fubini theorem applies and why the lemma $i\omega \to \partial_x$ can be applied to the resulting function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be simpler to work out the direct transform in terms of distributions. If $1/x$ is defined by
$$\left( \frac 1 x, \phi \right) =
\operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {\phi(x)} x dx,$$
then
$$\mathcal F[\operatorname{sgn} x] = -\frac {2 i} w, \\
\mathcal F\left[ \frac 1 {x^2+1} \right] = \pi e^{-\left| w \right|}, \\
\mathcal F\left[ \frac {i \operatorname{sgn} x} {x^2+1} \right] =
 \frac 1 w * e^{-\left| w \right|} =
 \operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_{-\infty}^\infty
  \frac {e^{-\left| w - \tau \right|}} \tau d\tau = \\
 e^{-w} \operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_{-\infty}^w \frac {e^\tau} \tau d\tau +
 e^w \operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_w^\infty \frac {e^{-\tau}} \tau d\tau = \\
 e^{-w} \operatorname{Ei}(w) - e^w \operatorname{Ei}(-w).$$
Taking the distributional derivative, we indeed obtain
$$\mathcal F^{-1}\left[
 w e^{-w} \operatorname{Ei}(w) - w e^w \operatorname{Ei}(-w) \right] =
-\frac {2 \left| x \right|} {(x^2+1)^2} + 2 \delta(x),$$
where the first term is an ordinary function.